# Error when tring to use tgui c++

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, sfml

I have been building a game using SFML in c++ on windows.  I have now finished the game and I have been trying to create a GUI using TGUI because it looked simple and easy to use.  I have set it up in my VC++ project and compiled a seemingly simple piece of code.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    tgui::Gui gui(window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            gui.handleEvent(event);
        }

        window.clear();
        gui.draw();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine, however immediately when I start the code I get an 
Unhandled exception at 0x80002610 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x80002610.

I was wondering where the access violation could possibly be coming from.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure you correctly configured your project & followed 1:1 the tutorials). Look at this comment for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086134/sfml-displaying-sprite-error-0xc0000005-access-violation-reading-location-0x00d?rq=1#comment33498473_22086134 If it doesn't solve your problem -> use a debugger

Comment: I think I might have a wrong version of SFML installed, I reinstalled it and it worked.